# Twig forgets array-keys

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I have a weird problem with twig in Symfony2. I am using the following array:

```
[days] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [money] => 9
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [money] => 21
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [money] => 38
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [money] => 6
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [money] => 6
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [money] => 3
            )

        [31] => Array
            (
                [money] => 11
            )

    )
```

to test this I used the following code

```
{% for key in days %}
  {{ key }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

but the output shows the following

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

but it should look like this

```
1
2
3
4
18
19
31
```

Looks like twig creates a new array with new indexes. Is there a way to get the right index from array?

With `var_dump($days)` in php I can see the right index, so the "problem" is related to twig.

Comment: Hi igorw,I don't want the money value, I need the key from the parent array.

Comment: Try `{% debug days %}`, I'm betting that's the value in twig (`array_values`,`array_shift`,etc). Chances are something is reindexing the array. Is the first value your showing what your passing into `$twig_env->render( $days );`?

Comment: @KendallHopkins: The problem got already fixed. It's not relayed on twig, it's a known gap in doctrine-mongodb.

Comment: It's not related on twig, it's a known gap in doctrine-mongodb using embeddedDocuments.
Doctrine can't handle key-Values from embeddedDocuments, it will reorder the keys beginning from 0 and will so ignore the right key-values.
Thank you anyway for your help :).

Comment: @Monty Make sure to answer the question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not related on twig, it's a known gap in doctrine-mongodb using embeddedDocuments. Doctrine can't handle key-Values from embeddedDocuments, it will reorder the keys beginning from 0 and will so ignore the right key-values. Thank you anyway for your help :).

Answer (score 15):

also you can try this :

```
{% for key,value in users %}
    {{ key }}
{% endfor %}
```

or maybe look into the "loop" object defined in the for loop

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this

http://www.twig-project.org/doc/templates.html

By default, a loop iterates over the values of the sequence. You can iterate on keys by using the keys filter:

```
<h1>Members</h1>
<ul>
  {% for key in users|keys %}
    <li>{{ key }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, same issue with |keys ... :(

Comment: @Monty I tried to emulate your setup, and this solution worked for me (incidentally, {{ key }} didn't work at all)... can you post the code you're using in the action as well?

Comment: Hi Problematic, I posted th whole code on github/twig: https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/347. I forgot the the second value in for, as imagend by azat, but it doesn't work, too.