# Reference array from key in for loop with Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In Twig I am trying to iterate over a potentially incomplete array using a fixed-length for loop so I can show what values are empty.

In PHP this would be simplified to:

```
for($i =0; $i <= $limit; $i++) {
    if($data[$i]) {
        echo $data[$i];
    }
)
```

The only thing is that in Twig I am having problems using the key (index) of the loop to reference a value in an array, this is what I've tried and expected to work, but doesn't:

```
{% for i in range(0, limit-1) %}
    {{ data.i }}
{% endfor %}
```

I could obviously use `array_pad()` to pad out my array in my controller, but surely there must be a way to do this in twig?

Comment: You could check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197499/twig-forgets-array-keys

Comment: @OptimusCrime I've looked at that, not relevant.

Comment: You say it does not work. What is happening instead?

Comment: When I do `{{ data.i }}`, it is looking for `$data['i']`, instead of parsing `i` as the index of the loop and looking for `data.2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
{% for i in range(0, limit-1) %}
  {% if data[i] is defined %}
    {{ data[i] }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can use the `..` operator to create a range `{% for i in 0..limit-1 %}`