# key value being replaced by 'key' when using merge() in twig

Tags: php, symfony, merge, key, twig

I am trying to add pairs of key value to an array with their current values for all those attributes not starting by '_'. For some reason, the merge replaces the value of "key" (i.e slug) with the string 'key'.

For example when slug is the only attribute with key not starting with '_',

```
key = slug
value = something
```

it behaves as follows:

```
{% for key,value in app.request.attributes.all %}
    {% if '_' != key | slice(0, 1) %}
        {{ dump(key) }}  // string(4) "slug"
        {% set params = params | merge({ key : value}) %}
        {{ dump(key) }} // string(4) "slug"
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{ dump(params) }} // array(1) { ["key"]=> string(9) "something" }
```

I have added what the dumps return next to them.

The final dump returns

```
array(1) { ["key"]=> string(9) "something" }
```

while i'm expecting

```
array(1) { ["slug"]=> string(9) "something" }
```

I'd say it's a similar problem to [Twig forgets array-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197499/twig-forgets-array-keys) but the conclusion on that question is that is a mongodb problem and I am not using it. I am working with attributes from the request.

For some reason, the merge({ key : value}) is behaving as merge({ 'key' : value}).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to wrap your variable with parenthesis to be able to use it as a key.

```
{% set params = params | merge({ (key) : value}) %}
```

Comment: You are welcome, consider validating this answer as the right one, thanks!

Comment: doing something like this in a foreach :   

{% set years = years | merge({ (year) : year}) %}

getting that :  

  1 => string '2014' (length=4)
  2 => string '2014' (length=4)

Comment: Using the code in this answer may not behave as desired if you are using numeric values as your keys.  Twig's `merge` filter uses PHPs `array_merge` method which renumbers numeric values. This post describes one possible work around (placing underscores in from of your number values): http://obtao.com/blog/2014/06/use-variable-key-twig-array/

Answer (score 5):

With numeric keys you can lose your key in the process, with the `merge`filter.

I couldn't find any documentation about the '+' operator applied with arrays, but it works well in this case:

```
{% set array = {(1): 2} + array %}
```

Source: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2741#issuecomment-417445042

Comment: Thanks for this. I used: `('id_' ~ number_variable)` to get round this problem of keys being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

[@laurent-w](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1408100/laurent-w) you saved me.

I'll share my code, maybe it can save someone too

```
{% set payment_methods_keys = {} %}
{% for business_key, business_array in business %}
    {% for keys, saved_payment_method in business[business_key].saved_payment_methods %}
        {% set payment_methods_keys = {(business_key): keys} + payment_methods_keys %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}


<script type="text/javascript">
    function addPaymentMethod(businessKey) {
        let payment_methods_keys = JSON.parse('{{ payment_methods_keys | json_encode | raw }}');
        console.log(payment_methods_keys[businessKey]) //Result {2: 1, 8: 2}
</script>
```